# How to show that any finite Abelian Group with a certain property is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, totient-function

Here is the problem:

> Suppose $(G, .)$ is a finite Abelian group and has the property that $\forall k \in N, |\{ g ∈ G : g^k = e \}| ≤ k$. Show that G is cyclic.

And this is my lecturer's proof:

> Let $n = |G|$. It is enough to show that $G$ has an element of order $n$. If $g \in G, g \ne e$ then it's order $d$ divides $n$. Moreover $H = \langle g \rangle$ contains all elements of order $d$. As $H$ is a cyclic group of order $d$, it follows that the number of elements of order $d$ in $H$ (and therefore in $G$) is $\phi(d)$. Thus, the number of elements of $G$ of order $d$ is $\phi(d)$. Since $\sum_{d|n} \phi(d) = n$ if $d|n$, then number of elements of $G$ of order $d$ is $\phi(d)$. In particular, there are $\phi(n)$ elements of $G$ of order $n$. As $\phi(n) \ne0$, $G$ is therefore cyclic.

What I'm having trouble understanding is where in the proof the fact that $G$ is Abelian and the property is used. In other words where does this argument fall apart for any general group.

Comment: $|\{ g ∈ G : g^d = e \}| ≤ d$ and $H$ contains $d$ number of elements.

Comment: for every $h = g^m ∈ H$, we have $h^d = g^md = e$

Comment: The hypothesis that the group is abelian is indeed not necessary. Also, it should read "Thus, the number of elements of $G$ of order $d$ is *at most* $\phi(d)$". The counting argument after then shows that number is *exactly* $\phi(d)$.

Comment: The proof is unclear to me. Indeed, if $|g|=d$ then $G$ has $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$. But then he concludes that there are $\phi(n)$ elements of $G$ of order $n$. But that requires existence of $g$ such that $|g|=n$, right? Ergo it assumes $G$ is cyclic to begin with. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is lemma 2 p.4 of Serre A course in arithmetic. The hypothesis abelian is not needed.

Comment: @freakish That's what I thought as well, so if that's the case where should I go from there?

Comment: @TsemoAristide Thanks I'll have a look

Comment: @freakish Every element of the group has an order $d$ dividing $n$. For each $d\mid n$, there are at most $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$ by the first part of the argument. But then  $|G|=\sum_{d\mid n}|\{g\in G\colon\mathrm{ord}(g)=d\}|\le\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d)=n=|G|$, so we must have equality, i.e. exactly $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$ for each $d$.

Comment: I would borrow this book from my uni library but it's closed due to quarantine :(